# Animation Nodes - Blend distribution of objects on a curve into another curve

Tags: animation, animation-nodes, soft-body, splines, matrix

I've been trying to recreate the effect from the Cinema 4D tutorial below:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BPv2HVvQfGo

I'm stuck at 9:55 where he uses the inheritance effector to be able to morph instanced cubes from the first path into the other. Is it possible to do it in Animation Nodes? I've been trying for a few days and I couldn't find a way to do it.

Or maybe there's another way to achieve this effect in Blender? I've tried connecting splines and trimming the bottom one. It works kinda well but the connection is very sharp and I don't know how to smooth only the connection, not the whole shape.

[image: Animation Nodes - Blend distribution of objects on a curve into another curve]

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Yes, it is possible to achieve this with Animation Nodes. Just for clarification, do you only want to morph the distribution of objects from one path to another path (different shape) and/or also want to morph the curve?

Comment: I wanted to do it as in the Cinema 4D tutorial above, so to morph the distribution of objects from one path to another path and then trace the objects to create the final curve. Morphing curves would do the job as well, I think. Anyway, how can I do it? After that, I need a falloff to control the animation to look as in the tutorial.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

First, I'll show how to morph objects distribution from one curve to another curve then we will use the same node-tree to morph a curve.

==========================================

**Morphing Object-Distributions:**
**1)** First, we have to sample the curves (A and B) which we will use to distribute the objects, both curve's sample-amount should be the same:
[image]

**2)** Now, we have to mix the locations or vector-lists of both the curves and the mix factor is controlled by the falloff. To do that, we can use the *Mix Vector* node but for vector-list, we also need a Loop node. However, for better performance, I have made a group-node which do the same job i.e., mix the two vector-lits (A and B):
[image]

**3)** Next step, mix the locations of both curves using the group-node (mentioned in step 2) then use the resultant locations to distribute the objects:
[image]

**4)** You can use any falloff to animate the object-distributions. Here, I have used the Delay Falloff node to animate the distributions:
[image]

**5)** And also use the same group-node to mix the other vector-lists, e.g., Tangents of both the curves:
[image]

Here is the final node-tree:
[image]

Blend File:

[image]

==========================================

**Morphing Curves:** We can also use the resultant locations from group-node to create a spline for curve morphing:
[image]

Blend File:

[image]

==========================================

**Edit:**

**Morphing Object-Distributions on multi-splines:**
We can easily morph the object-distributions on multi-splines use Loop Node. In this example, I use the above node-tree with a single spline (A) and loop/iterate over other splines (B list):

[image]

Final node-tree:
[image]

Blend File:

[image]

Comment: I started to go in this direction of thinking but it would take me at least another few days of studying Animation Nodes to finally make it. Thank you very much for speeding it up by providing such a complex description and the blend files. You're great!