# It"s possible to morph a spline in multi-spline controling the delay on time?

Tags: animation-nodes, splines

moving in the same direction of this idea -Morphing Object-Distributions on multi-splines([Animation Nodes - Blend distribution of objects on a curve into another curve](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/155670/animation-nodes-blend-distribution-of-objects-on-a-curve-into-another-curve)), i find the way to morph spline in multispline but i dont know how to offset this distribution on time. I need some help.

Comment: To offset the time use Time Delay node.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. I have found it by chance playing with the trim spline node 
 and noise falloff inside a loop.https://drive.google.com/file/d/1iqo0RRLqMOjWQlj4ZYs8HTnF0BGtCnBZ/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Any suggestions would be welcome. https://drive.google.com/open?id=1BUi8weqt5RGvn8QODO_OoDMp2XDV5uy8

Comment: And the new step forward -https://drive.google.com/open?id=1AdfJdiRfZ_634mi1Oa1TwOsUGC99qJJQ

Comment: It looks like you want to create a cloth weaving effect. I think you can use this setup https://i.stack.imgur.com/fIADZ.png

Comment: yes, that was the starting point, ..thanks for this setup, it is useful and has inspired me a lot.